Regex negative lookahead with variable text before and after keywords
I have a string which contains two keywords, keyword_1 and keyword_2, and an integer which follows on keyword_2.
I want to extract the integer, but only if a particular keyword, keyword_neg, does not occur between keyword_1 and keyword_2.
Additionally (and I believe this is where the problem is coming from), there may be more random text between all 3 keywords.
I have tried a large number of different regex to do so, but with no success. For the first test string in the code snippet below, the regex returns the number 9, but should return nothing. To avoid making "translation" errors to a more abstract example, here are the original strings/regex with which I have been working:
keyword_1 is "ISIN ABC123"
keyword_2 is "Fondets omløpshastighet er"
keyword_neg is "ISIN"
import re
#The following string should return nothing, because between "ISIN ABC123" and "Fondets omløpshastighet er", the word "ISIN" occurs
str_that_should_return_nothing = "ISIN ABC123 blabla ISIN DEF123 Fondets omløpshastighet er 9 blabla"

#The following string should return 5 because the word "ISIN" does not appear between "ISIN ABC123" and "Fondets omløpshastighet er"
str_that_should_return_5 = "ISIN ABC123 blabla Fondets omløpshastighet er 5 ISIN DEF123 Fondets omløpshastighet er 9 blabla"

pattern = 'ISIN ABC123.*?(?!ISIN).*?Fondets omløpshastighet er (\d)' #does NOT work
match = re.findall(pattern, str_that_should_return_nothing )
print("str_1_f: ", match)
match = re.findall(pattern, str_that_should_return_5)
print("str_2_t: ", match)

Please help :)

PLEASE NOTE: the problem is caused by the various necessary .*? regex expressions combined with the negative lookahead and I found no question that was asked about this and answered

See https://regex101.com/r/8MAPCY/1

Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you so much! :) Do you want to provide a full answer, then I can mark it as solved. Would you mind elaborating on this part of the solution: "(?:(?!ISIN).)*?"

All done here and here.
